# How to return data to ajaxError in Perl

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, perl

In JavaScript I capture errors in this way:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) {
    handleError(MSG_SAVE_ERROR);
});
```

How do I return my message from Perl code if I have server error? 
I use `$SIG{__DIE__}` to intercept exceptions.

I tried this:

```
$SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
    my ($error) = @_;
    my $q=new CGI;

    print $q->header(-type=>"text/plain", -Access_Control_Allow_Origin=>"*")."My error: ".$error;
}
```

but it does not work, `error` and `fail` in **jqxhr** is empty.

Comment: what about `thrownError` argument? did you try that?

Comment: in `thrownError`  I have text  `"Server Error"`

Comment: Have you verified that the Perl part works as you expect? Can you see the response with _My error_ in your developer tools in the browser? You might also want to look at how CGI::Carp implements `fatalsToBrowser`.

Comment: [CGI.pm is no longer considered good practice for developing web applications, including quick prototyping and small web scripts. There are far better, cleaner, quicker, easier, safer, more scalable, more extensible, more modern alternatives available at this point in time. These will be documented with CGI::Alternatives.](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#CGI.pm-HAS-BEEN-REMOVED-FROM-THE-PERL-CORE)

Comment: I don't find my error in developer tools in my browser and I would like use $SIG{__DIE__} if it is possible

Answer (score 1):

The error state is determined by the [HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

By default CGI will output a `200 OK` response. Errors are codes in the range 4xx and 5xx.

The [CGI POD has an example of sending an error code](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#Creating-a-standard-http-header):

```
print $cgi->header(
    -type       => 'image/gif',
    -nph        => 1,
    -status     => '402 Payment required',
    -expires    => '+3d',
    -cookie     => $cookie,
    -charset    => 'utf-8',
    -attachment => 'foo.gif',
    -Cost       => '$2.00'
);
```

The only significant hash key there is the `-status`, which you should set to an appropriate error code for your error.

Comment: ok, but how return my data (error from perl) to javascript when I have error 500?

Comment: @sydnej — Keep doing what you are doing. Just add the status code.

Comment: `print $cgi->header(-type=>"text/plain", -status => '500 Server Error', -Access_Control_Allow_Origin=>"*")."My error: ".$error;` it is correct? In js error and fail in jqxhr are empty. Status is 500 and status text is "Server Error"

Comment: @sydnej — jqXHR's `fail` property should be a *function* (as should `error`, but that is deprecated). You should be looking at `status`, `statusTest` and `responseText`. Have you looked at [the documentation for it](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)?

Comment: in `responseText` i have default text from apache, not "My error:"